# Switch Do not Disturb and Silent mode based on schedule automatically

Tags: automation, silent-mode, do-not-disturb

I always have my phone on silent. I use my Garmin watch to give me notifications, then look at my phone and pick up if needed, etc.

However, during the night, I'd like to allow my parents to call me and for my phone to ring (aloud) so that it wakes me up as they're old and it may be an emergency. (I don't wear my watch at night).

I realise that I can set up a DND profile and allow "starred contacts" to call me, however this means that every night I need to remember to turn my ringer on, so that once the DND setting has allowed the call through, I can hear my phone ringing.

Is there any way to automatically make my phone move to "ring" rather than "silent" at the same time as DND kicks in, or is there another way?

Phone is a Pixel 6.

Answer (score 0):

I have used LLama Location Profile before but its no longer being updated.  I would suggest [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate)

> Automate your repetitive or complex tasks:
>  Manage files on your device and remote storage
> ☁️ Backup apps and files
> ✉️ Send and receive messages
>  Control phone calls
>  Access online content
>  Take pictures, record audio and video
> ️ Configure device settings
>  Integrate apps
> ⏰ Start manually, based on your location, time of day and other triggers

There are others such as Tasker and IFTTT but I havent used them much.